# Django custom field method does not create enum field in mysql

Tags: django, django-models

My code is as shown below:

```
class CharMaxlength25Field(models.Field):
    def db_type(self, connection):
        return 'enum(android,ios)'



class search(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'search'

    city_name = CharMaxlength25Field()
```

Through this code, I am trying to create `enum` field in mysql. Now when I try to run this schema with `python manage.py makemigrations` step,I get the following error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'android,ios) NULL' at line 1")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add quotes:

```
class CharMaxlength25Field(models.Field):
    def db_type(self, connection):
        return 'enum("android","ios")'
```